# i want to build hardware wallet from scratch

Tags: wallets, cryptography, ledger-nano-s, hardware-wallets

I hope this message finds you well. I am currently embarking on a project to build my own hardware wallet, similar to popular devices like the Ledger.

Firstly, I'd like to know what components are necessary to build a functional hardware wallet. Apart from the obvious need for a secure microcontroller, I assume there are other essential parts like a display, buttons for user input, and a secure element for key storage. Could you please help me compile a list of the necessary components and their specifications? Additionally, if there are any specific brands or models that you recommend, I would greatly appreciate your insights.

Furthermore, I'm curious if there is any readily available source code or open-source projects that I can refer to while building my hardware wallet. It would be immensely helpful to have a solid foundation or reference implementation to ensure the security and functionality of my device. If you know of any existing projects, particularly ones resembling the Ledger's architecture, I would be grateful if you could share the relevant information.

I understand that building a hardware wallet involves complex considerations, particularly regarding security and firmware development. Therefore, any advice, best practices, or resources you can offer would be highly valuable to me. If you have any personal experiences with similar projects or if you know of any other forums or communities dedicated to hardware wallet development, please feel free to mention them as well.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance. I'm excited to dive into this project and look forward to your insights and suggestions.

Comment: The question is interesting but out of scope for a site like this. If you search you will find instructions how to build your own hardware wallet https://www.instructables.com/Making-My-Own-Trezor-Crypto-Hardware-Wallet/.